# Java reluctant matching from both sides of the quantifier

Tags: java, regex, reluctant-quantifiers

I would like to write a regex in java which will find the shortest available match from both sides of the quantifier.

For example, for this pattern `"a.*?b"` apllied to `"aaaaaacbbbbbbb"`:

i would like to find `"acb"` but i get `"aaaaaacb"`.

Anyone has an idea which regex i can use for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mimic reluctant matching from the start by discarding a greedy `.*`. In this case, this would become `.*(a.*?b)`, if you get group number 1:

```
String example = "aaaaaacbbbbbbb";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*(a.*?b)").matcher(example);
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the shortest sequence that starts with an `'a'` and ends with a `'b'`. That means that between the initial `'a'` and the final `'b'´, neither an`'a'`nor a`'b'` may appear (otherwise there would be a shorter such sequence contained in the match), thus

```
"a[^ab]*b"
```

would find a minimal such sequence (the first occurring in the searched string, or all such, depending on how you search).

I'm not au courant with the syntax of lazy vs. greedy matching, I think

```
"a[^a]*?b"
```

would do the same, match an `'a'`, the minimal sequence of non-`'a'`s until the next `'b'` is found.

Comment: @alex23 I'm not removing it, I'm matching all neither-a-nor-b-s between the a and the b.